# Automatic service discovery protocols

Tags: java, api, protocols, service-discovery

I am currently looking into a variety of service discovery protocols available to Java and have come up with a small list:

- **DNS-SD**<sup>[[1](http://www.dns-sd.org/)]</sup> a.k.a *mDNS* - implemented by [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) and also used as a backend for [Zeroconf/Bonjour discovery provider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Providers#Zeroconf.2Faka_Bonjour.2FRendevous) for ECF (Eclipse Communication Framework)
- **UPnP**<sup>[[2](http://www.upnp.org/)]</sup> - implemented by [Cling](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/) library
- **SLP** - implemented by [OpenSLP](http://openslp.sourceforge.net/) and [jSLP](http://jslp.sourceforge.net/) projects (later is also available as [ECF Discovery provider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Providers#jSLP_aka_SLP.2FRFC2608))

There's probably more options, if so, I invite you to add tham to the mix.

I would love to get some objective listings of each protocol's pros and cons from people who have used one or many of these. How does implementation of publishing and discovering a service look like, what is the "chattiness" of the protocol, how reliable is it (both - the protocol and the implementations), does it require centralized service directory or is it p2p/decentralized etc.

Which one would you choose to provide seamless automatic discovery of multiple devices/services on the LAN?

Answer (score 3):

jmdns - the underlying algorithms are much simpler than uPnP.  Simplicity counts here.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is old, I will dovetail into the answer that suggested using ZooKeeper.

Netflix released [Curator](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/introducing-curator-netflix-zookeeper.html), a framework and client wrapper around ZooKeeper, which includes (among other recipies) a [Service Discovery](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Service-Discovery) extension.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) can be used for service discovery as well

Comment: Maybe you could edit this answer to include some reasoning behind this choice